# Replace an old shortcode with a new one

Tags: php, wordpress

I've some problems replacing an old shortcode (generated by a plugin incompatible with the latest versions of Wordpress) with a custom one.
My idea is to write some code in functions.php to detect the old plugin text  `[ultimatesocial networks= “facebook, twitter, google, pinterest, whatsapp, mail” align=”left”]` and change it with the new one `[social]`.
This is the code I've tried:

```
function replace_shortcode( $text ) {
    $replace = array(
        'ultimatesocial networks= “facebook, twitter, google, pinterest, whatsapp, mail” align=”left”' => 'social',
    );
    $text = str_replace( array_keys($replace), $replace, $text );
    return $text;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'replace_shortcode' );
    add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'replace_shortcode' );
```

It doesn't work. I think the problem are the quotation marks in the old shortcode but also using an escape character into the array can't help me.

Any idea? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you specify the "it doesn't work" part? What's the error or the unwanted result you currently get? Because the function seems to work just find.

Comment: Looks like the weird quotes are in use. Need the uncurly `"` double-quote character. (likely copy/pasted from some other source?)

Comment: @YTZ : It doesn't work means that nothing happens: the function doesn't detect the old shortcode. Maybe I can try replacing quotes with the equivalent HTML entities...